# Извлеч информацию из ошибки HttpClientErrorException при работе с restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, header

Я вызываю

```
ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlRemoveCard, HttpMethod.POST, requestBody, Message.class);
```

проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как обработать ответ от urlRemoveCard. urlRemoveCard это url к вневнему сервису. В свагере указано, что если все хорошо, то приходит код 200 и message ".....".

но при различных других вариантах предусмотренны ошибки разных статусов.

К примеру если случается HttpClientErrorException то может вернуться ошибка

code 1800009
message "......."

Мне нужно из любого ответа извлекать данные и сохранять в Response.class который содержит поля code и message. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что когда случается Exeption я просто перехватываю его, где в строке записан код и сообщение. Мне нужно вытащить из этой строки данные, а это очень не удобно.

Можно ли как то перехватывать ответ и доставать из него код и сообщение?

фрагмент свагера.

Message это простой объект

```
@Data
public class Message {
    private String code;
    private String message;
}
```

Comment: Так в `catch` заполняйте объект `Message` из данных в `HttpClientErrorException`, не?

Comment: да это хорошая идея. но почему то в HttpClientErrorException содержиться сразу поле detailMessage: 400 Bad Request: [{"code":138773,"message":"пользователя не существует"}]. а из него доставать как то не удобно и я подумал может есть способ сразу сущность перехватывать

Comment: там должен быть метод `getResponseBodyAsString()`, унаследованный от `RestClientResponseException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватывайте `RestClientException`

И доставайте что вам нужно))
Как вариант

```
Exception ex = ....
//Получаем исключение
String responseBody = ex.getMessage();
//Если это ошибка ответа
if (ex instanceof RestClientResponseException) {
    //получаем тело ответа
    responseBody = ((RestClientResponseException) ex).getResponseBodyAsString();
}
//Тут что-то делаете с responseBody
```